# Find a central force given the orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, vectors, coordinate-systems

I've been trying to solve the following problem for a long time.

Let's consider a particle of mass $m$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with polar coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$. The particle moves on the orbit described by the equation $r=2a\sin\theta,\,\,a>0$, with velocity $|\mathbf{v}|=k/\sin^2\theta,\,\,k>0$.

The task is to show that the force is central and to determine such a force.

My idea has been to use the two equations given to prove the two components \begin{equation}
F_\theta=m\left( r\,\ddot\theta + 2\dot{r}\,\dot\theta - r\,\dot\varphi^2\sin\theta\cos\theta \right)\\
F_\phi=m\left( r\ddot\varphi\,\sin\theta + 2\dot{r}\,\dot\varphi\,\sin\theta + 2 r\,\dot\theta\,\dot\varphi\,\cos\theta \right)
\end{equation}
 to vanish; unfortunately, I wasn't able to get to any interesting result.

Can anybody give me some help on this?

Comment: I am not sure if these equations of motion make sense, since usually $r$ is positive, however in your equation it can be negative as well, and the velocity will be infinite when $\sin\theta=0$.

Comment: No, $r$ can't be negative, since $0<\theta<\pi$. Velocity can be infinite, but only in the case $r=0$; I have supposed this to be a singularity for the force

Comment: You are right, I swapped the meaning of $\theta$ with $\varphi$.

Comment: Those are spherical coordinates and not polar. Since there is no dependence on $\phi$ I suppose $F_{\phi} = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An orbit in three dimensions is generally specified by giving how **three** quantities depend on time, or by giving how **two** coordinates depend on the third one.You have however omittied saying how $\phi$ depends on $\theta$; I will thus simply assume that $\phi$ is a constant, hence $v_\phi = 0$.

In this case the total angular momentum
$$
\mathbf L = m\mathbf r\times\mathbf v
$$ 
is given by, in spherical coordinates:
$$
\mathbf L = mr \hat e_r\times (v_\theta\hat e_\theta + v_\phi\hat e_\phi) 
= -mrv_\theta\hat e_\phi
$$
If this turns out to be a constant, then we shall know that this is a central force.

However, we do not have $v_\theta$ yet, only the modulus $v$. For our orbit, we already know that $v_\phi = 0$. Also, 
$$
\dot r = 2a \cos\theta \dot \theta
$$
while
$$
v_\theta = r\dot\theta = 2 a \sin\theta\dot\theta\;.
$$
Putting all of this together, we find that
$$
|\mathbf v| = 2 a\dot\theta
$$
but we also know that
$$
|\mathbf v| = \frac{k}{\sin^2\theta}
$$
Hence
$$
\dot\theta = \frac{k}{2a}\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}
$$
which allows us to find that
$$
v_\theta = r\dot\theta = 2a\sin\theta \frac{k}{2a}\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} = \frac{k}{\sin\theta}
$$
and the only non-zero component of the angular momentum becomes
$$
\mathbf L = -mr v_\theta \hat e_\phi = - 2 a k m \hat e_\phi
$$which remains constant along the orbit, *i.e.* as $\theta$ changes. The force is central.

A central force has a potential that depends only on $r$, not on $\theta$ or $\phi$. The total energy, which is conserved, is
$$
E = \frac{m}{2}|\mathbf v|^2 + V(r)
$$ can now be rewritten as
$$
E = \frac{16 a^4 k^2 m}{r^4} + V(r)\;.
$$
This quantity must remain constant as $r$ varies along the orbit. The only way to obtain this is to have
$$
V(r) = -\frac{16 a^4 k^2 m}{r^4} + V_0
$$
with $V_0$ a constant.

Comment: Great, many thanks. Probably the exercise is not exactly well stated, since it doesn't say anything about $\phi$. I guess your assumption about it is right.

Answer (score 1):

Using conservation of angular momentum you have (note that this relation implies a monotonic relation between angle and time)
$$
mr^2\dot{\varphi}=J\Rightarrow\mathrm{d}t=\frac{mr^2}{J}\mathrm{d}\varphi.
$$
The energy is conserved and given by,
$$
E=\frac{1}{2}m\dot r^2+\frac{J^2}{2mr^2}+V(r).
$$
Changing variables from time to angle ($\dot r=r_\varphi \frac{J}{mr^2}$)
$$
E=\frac{1}{2}\frac{J^2}{mr^4}r'^2(\varphi)+\frac{J^2}{2mr^2}+V(r).
$$
Noting that $\frac{r'(\varphi)}{r^2}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varphi}\frac{1}{r(\varphi)}$, we change to the variable $u(\varphi)=\frac{1}{r(\varphi)}$. The conservation of energy in terms of $u$ reads 
$$
E=\frac{1}{2}\frac{J^2}{m}u'^2(\varphi)+\frac{J^2}{2m}u^2(\varphi)+V(\frac{1}{u(\varphi)}).
$$
That is, give a trajectory $r(\varphi)$ the potential is given by
$$
V(\frac{1}{u(\varphi)})=E-\frac{1}{2}\frac{J^2}{m}u'^2(\varphi)-\frac{J^2}{2m}u^2(\varphi).
$$

In your case start by assuming its central force and find the potential.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your answer: I can't assume the force to be central, since it's what I have to prove.

Comment: You can assume, and if you find a potential under this assumption that it proves your assumption.

Comment: You can also use the above to show that the force is given by $F(r)=\frac{J^2}{mr^4}(r''(\varphi)-\frac{2}{r}r'^2-r)$.
If the RHS is angle independent then it means that the orbit can be satisfied by a central force.
In your case the force is $F(r)=-\frac{8a^2}{r}$

Comment: @PhysicistRRE - Showing that a central force is consistent with the givens is a sufficient condition. It does not prove the conjecture unless you can also show that it is a necessary condition.

Comment: @PhysicistRRE - Wouldn't I obtain a potential with a dependence on total energy and total angular momentum?

Answer (score 0):

Using energy conservation you can find your answer from
$$
V = E-\frac{1}{2}mv^2
$$
Express $V$ in terms of $r$ and you should get the form of the potential, assuming that it is a central force. Then you have to show that the assumption is correct.

Is the problem such that you can assume $\varphi =0$?

Answer (score 0):

Using differential geometry one can show that

$$ \vec{p}(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 a \sin \theta \cos \theta \\ 2 a \sin \theta^2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \vec{v}(\theta,\dot\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{pmatrix} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 a \cos(2 \theta) \dot{\theta} \\ 2 a \sin(2 \theta) \dot{\theta}  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \vec{a}(\theta,\dot\theta,\ddot\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} x'' \\ y'' \\ z'' \end{pmatrix} = \frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 a \left(\ddot{\theta}\cos(2\theta) - 2 \dot{\theta}^2 \sin(2 \theta)\right)\\
2 a \left(\ddot{\theta}\sin(2\theta) + 2 \dot{\theta}^2 \cos(2 \theta)\right) \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

and the orbit radius of curvature $\rho(\theta)$

$$ \frac{1}{\rho(\theta)} = \frac{|y' x'' - y'' x'|}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{1.5}} = \frac{8 a^2 \dot{\theta}^3 }{(4 a^2 \dot{\theta}^2)^{1.5}} = \frac{1}{a}  $$

So if the curvature is constant, then the orbit is circular.

At any point, if the tangent direction is $\vec{e}$ and the normal direction $\vec{n}$ then the kinematic decomposition is

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{v} & = v \vec{e} \\
\vec{a} & = \dot{v} \vec{e}  + \frac{v^2}{\rho} \vec{n} \end{aligned}$$

Given that $|\vec{v}| = v = \frac{k}{\sin^2\theta}$ and thus $\dot{v} = - \frac{k \cos(\theta) \dot{\theta}}{\sin^3( \theta)}$

Together you have:

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{v} & = \frac{k}{\sin^2(\theta)} \vec{e}(\theta) \\
\vec{a} & = - \frac{k \cos(\theta) \dot{\theta}}{\sin^3( \theta)} \vec{e}(\theta)  + \frac{k^2}{a \sin^4(\theta)} \vec{n}(\theta) \\ \vec{F} & = m \vec{a} \end{aligned}$$